# Request method 'POST' not supported | SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, post

I'm trying to mount a simple start menu and I get an error in the POST method when I press the submit button.

My controller with the post method called by the submit in html with value "login"

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("usuario")
public class UsuarioControlador {

   @Autowired
    private UsuarioServicio usuarios;

   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET )
   public String index(ModelMap modelMap){
       modelMap.put("usuario",new Usuario());
       return "usuario/index";
   }

   //@PostMapping("/login")
   @RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String login(@ModelAttribute("usuario")Usuario usuario,HttpSession session,ModelMap modelMap){

      if(usuarios.findByUserId(usuario.getIdUsuario())!=null){  
          session.setAttribute("informacion", usuario.getInformacion());
          return "usuario/welcome";

      }else{
          modelMap.put("error", "Usuario no valido");
          return "usuario/index";
      }

   }


}
```

My index.html with the submit call "login"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/usuario/login}" 
        th:objects="${usuario}" method="post">

<table cellpading="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td>Usuario</td>
    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{idUsuario}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="login" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
<br/>
<span th:text="${error}"></span>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to set content-type and accept headers

Comment: Provide your code inline as text, not as images.

Comment: It´s my first time here sorry, I just modified it...

Comment: Please add a stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the @RequestMapping tag, to match with the form action /usuario/login, the slash sign its missing.
Replace 
@RequestMapping("usuario")
with
@RequestMapping("/usuario")

And Replace
@RequestMapping(value="login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
with 
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: Thx for answer, i have applied the changes but it still doesn´t work... same error

Comment: The first thing I've think was the same, @mival, but if it doesn't work, a stack trace probably will help to clear the point